# Generating generic paths for STI models in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

Suppose I have a Rails 4 application that manages `Widget` objects, and using Simple Table Inheritance I have specialisations `Widget::Foo` and `Widget::Bar`.

I would like to manage all my `Widget` objects through a single `WidgetsController`.

I have the following models:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base; end

class Widget::Foo < Widget
  # Foo specific details...
end

class Widget::Bar < Widget
  # Bar specific details...
end
```

And a simple controller:

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @widgets = Widget.all
  end

  def show
    @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

My routes include

```
resources :widgets, only: [:index, :show}
```

In my `index.html.haml` I have something like:

```
- @widgets.each do |widget|
  = link_to "View your widget!", [@widget]
```

Which is where everything goes wrong.

Between `url_for` and `polymorphic_path` Rails will attempt to find a `widget_foo_path`, rather than using the extant `widget_path`.

I would rather not add additional routes, or controllers, and I would prefer not to specify the url helper manually. Is there a way to tell Rails that `Widget::Foo` and `Widget::Bar` objects should be linked to using the `widget_path` helper?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving the issue by creating a mixin:

```
module GenericSTIRoutes
  def initialize(klass, namespace = nil, name = nil)
    super(klass, namespace, name)

    superklass = klass

    while superklass.superclass != ActiveRecord::Base
      superklass = superklass.superclass
    end

    @param_key          = _singularize(superklass.name)
    @route_key          = ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize(@param_key)
    @singular_route_key = @param_key.dup
    @route_key << "_index" if @plural == @singular
  end
end
```

And then modifying `Widget.model_name` as follows:

```
def self.model_name
  @_model_name ||= Class.new(ActiveModel::Name) do
    include GenericSTIRoutes
  end.new(self, nil)
end
```